# Attaching to jQuery UI Tooltip to openstreetmap marker

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, openstreetmap

I am trying to put a jQuery UI Marker but it's not showing up. To test I have added a title attribute to the H1 above my map and it is working fine.

I have tried a number of things like setting the marker's title using .attr() but this seems the most logical:

```
ic = "img/" + place.type + '/' + place.status + ".png";
marker = new OpenLayers.Icon(ic, size, 0);
placeMarker = new OpenLayers.Marker(new OpenLayers.LonLat(place.longitude,     
    place.latitude).transform(gg,sm), marker);
$(placeMarker).tooltip({ content: place.name });
placeLayer.addMarker(placeMarker);
```

As I said, the H1 tooltip works (and displays over the map so it isn't a z-index problem) but nothing shows up for marker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work around this I have created my own tooltip div that is moved around when the cursor moves. Then, when the cursor is above content that I want to tooltip, the div is shown and hidden:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    curX = e.pageX + 10;
    curY = e.pageY;

    tooltip = $("#tooltip");
    tooltip.css("left", curX);
    tooltip.css("top", curY);
 });
```